# Java begineers string manipulation/counting characters issue

Tags: java, string, counting

I am trying to count the number of terms in a string after it has been split... what is the best way for me to do so? 
this is the problem I am trying to solve:

> Create a program that reads in one line from the user and repeats the line back with all four-letter words removed.

Here is what I have so far...

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringEx1{
        public static void main(String[]args){
            String mytext;
            Scanner ab= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter text: ");
            mytext=ab.nextLine();
            String [] mytext=mytext.split(" ");
```

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to count the number of items in the array that results from `split`?

Comment: Yes, this is the issue that i am having

Comment: I think you are looking for `.size()`

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need `length()` based on your edit.

Comment: i tried using it, but I kept getting the cannot find symbol error

Comment: import java.util.*;
public class StringEx1{
 public static void main(String[]args){
  Scanner ab= new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter text: ");
  String mytext=ab.nextLine();
  String [] mytext1=mytext.split(" ");
  System.out.println(mytext1.length());
 }
}

Comment: In Java, `length` is a property (field) of the array, not a method; remove the parenthesis.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much everyone! :D

Comment: @KarinaMeowmeow You should post that as an answer, and accept it so others can find it easier

Answer (score 0):

@Mick Mnemonic answered the question perfectly with "

In Java, length is a property (field) of the array, not a method; remove the parenthesis."
Thank you for everyone's help!